# Why this class partial template specialization code does not work?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2015

```
#include <typeinfo>

struct NullType {};

template < typename T0, typename T1, typename T2 >
class Test
{
public:
    typedef int Type;
};

template< typename T0, typename T1 >
class Test< T0, T1, NullType >
{
public:
    typedef unsigned char Type;
};

template< typename T0 >
class Test< T0, NullType, NullType >
{
public:
    typedef double Type;
};

int main()
{
    typedef Test<int, int>::Type TargetType;

    printf("%s\n", typeid(TargetType).name());

    return 0;
}
```

I use visual C++ 2015 to  compile this C++ code, but it get an compile error :

```
>test.cpp(34): error C2976: 'Test' : too few template arguments
>test.cpp(13): see declaration of 'Test'
>test.cpp(34): error C2955: 'Test' : use of class template requires template argument list
>test.cpp(13): see declaration of 'Test'
```

I want to `Test<int, int>` use the second specialization of class Test.
but it seems that it does not work. What did I do wrong?

this is valid code:

```
#include <typeinfo>

struct NullType {};

template < typename T0 = NullType, typename T1 = NullType, typename T2 = NullType>
class Test
{
public:
    typedef int Type;
};

template< typename T0, typename T1 >
class Test< T0, T1, NullType >
{
public:
    typedef unsigned char Type;
};

template< typename T0 >
class Test< T0, NullType >
{
public:
    typedef double Type;
};

int main()
{
    typedef Test<int, int>::Type TargetType;

    printf("%s\n", typeid(TargetType).name());

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ok, i understand, partial template specialization is just provide a special class implement, when we use it, we must provide all template parameters, so in this case, i can set the default parameter of the default class. it will works well:

Answer (score 3):

Note that since c++11 and variadic template, you may do

```
template <typename ... Ts> struct Test;

template <typename T0, typename T1, typename T2>
struct Test<T0, T1, T2>
{
    using Type = int;
};

template <typename T0, typename T1>
struct Test<T0, T1>
{
    using Type = unsigned char;
};

template <typename T0>
struct Test<T0>
{
    using Type = double;
};

int main()
{
    using TargetType = Test<int, int>::Type;
    // Compile time check:
    static_assert(std::is_same<unsigned char, TargetType>::value, "unexpected type");
    // runtime check:
    std::cout << typeid(TargetType).name() << std::endl;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/22ff198a71d20f0b)